# Connecting to jupyter server in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Following JetBrain tutorial https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-ipython-notebook-with-product.html I still can't execute jupyter cell like [] print(2+2).

Answer (score -1):

**change port 8888 -> 8080**

GO to RUN -> Edit configurations and change port from 8888 to 8080 
Your jupyter cell should be well executed.